# Spring Request mapping issue with only one header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, header

I have a request mapping that I want to be invoked ONLY when the request has `Accept` Header as `application/json`

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/payment", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json" , produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Above looks good but when the browser is refreshed this endpoint is called because when we look at the browser request headers, `Accept` header looks like this below which has `*/*`

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
```

I only want to invoke this api only for application/json and not for everything else.
I tried adding another value to my header like `headers = Accept=application/json,!text/html` but that did not work.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the consumes attribute of @RequestMapping?

Answer (score 0):

add consumes="application/json"  in the @RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(path ="/payment", produces={"application/json"}, consumes="application/json" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: It is a GET request. Why do we need consumes?